# How to add a string to the output from powershell

Tags: powershell

I use this to get a list of folders containing .h files.
**

```
$type = "*.h"
$HDIRS = dir .\$type -Recurse |
Select-Object Directory -Unique |
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

** It gives me a list of folders.
Now I want "-I " before every foldername. Common string manipulation doesn't seem to work

Comment: the `Format-*` cmdlets DO NOT give you a string - nor do they give you standard PoSh objects. instead, they give you the chopped up chunks of your objects wrapped in _formatting code_. ///// so, DO NOT use them for anything other than FINAL output to the screen or a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

You still have rich objects after the select so to manipulate the strings you have to reference the one property you've selected "Directory"

```
$type = "*.h"
$HDIRS = Dir .\$type -Recurse |
Select-Object Directory -Unique |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.Directory = "-I" + $_.Directory
    $_
} |
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

This will result in `$HDIRS` looking like a list of folder paths like `-IC:\temp\something\something...`

However, the format output objects are generally not suitable for further consumption. It looks like you're interested in the strings you could simply make this a flat array of strings like:

```
$type = "*.h"
$HDIRS = Dir .\$type" -Recurse |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory -Unique |
ForEach-Object{ "-I" + $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mantra goes filter left, format right.

Our data:

```
$type = '.\*.h'
Get-ChildItem -Path $type -Recurse
```

The manipulation (filter):

```
Select-Object { "-I $($_.Directory)" } -Unique
```

And the format:

```
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

---

In many cases, PowerShell cmdlets allow you to pass scriptblocks (closures) to evaluate to values and that's what I'm doing above with the `Select-Object` call.